# Why use a enum to create the singleton pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns, singleton, enum

Why would you use an enum to create a singleton pattern?
To what purpose would it serve over a conventional singleton pattern?

I have seen the above used. The code uses an enum to create this pattern without benefit. It confuses the situation as the enum is not used to store a "set of named integral constants" but simply a method.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70689/what-is-an-efficient-way-to-implement-a-singleton-pattern-in-java

Comment: Thanks for the duplicates, though im not asking how its used, but in what situations it would be best. I'll rephrase

Comment: Note, that the singleton pattern itself is considered an antipattern, regardless how you implement it. (Having only one instance of a "normal" class is fine though)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You wouldn't use it.  It's mainly out there as an exercise to help you understand the interesting properties of java enums, for which there are a few uses beyond the more traditional C++ style uses.  It's less verbose and requires some relatively deep knowledge of the language, which makes it attractive to the "look how clever I am" breed of programmers.  You don't want to be that guy.